# Set text layout in table html column

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

have a question. How to set the column layout so that the writing is parallel to the top, here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 10%;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
  <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Lois</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
  <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Joe</td>
  <td>Swanson</td>
  <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Cleveland Netherland</td>
  <td>Brown</td>
  <td>$250</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want a layout like the following, I want the second column text aligned with the first column:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a `vertical-align: top` rule for `th`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td{
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 10%;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
  <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Lois</td>
  <td>Griffin</td>
  <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Joe</td>
  <td>Swanson</td>
  <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Cleveland Netherland</td>
  <td>Brown</td>
  <td>$250</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should target the 2nd child and set vertical align to top

```
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  vertical-align: top
}
```

---

**Live example**

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 10%;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>Griffin</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lois</td>
      <td>Griffin</td>
      <td>$150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td>
      <td>Swanson</td>
      <td>$300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cleveland Netherland</td>
      <td>Brown</td>
      <td>$250</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

---

**Reference**

[:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

[vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)